# GML coordinate into latitude and longitude CESIUM

Tags: geocoding, latitude-longitude, cesiumjs

I am using the following data [NewYork](https://cesiumjs.org/NewYork/) that you can download at the bottom.

I added the map to Cesium using './assets/map/NewYork/tileset.json'

When I load cesium, I have the 3d building setup correctly, and at the accurate location.

I used the function to get the long/lat when I click on a building =>

```
mouseClickRegistration.subscribe(({movement: {endPosition}}) => {
    const pickedFeature = this.viewer.scene.pick(endPosition);

    console.log(pickedFeature.getProperty('longitude'), pickedFeature.getProperty('latitude'));

    });
});
```

But this return me inaccurate value.

When I click on building let's say at

```
long:-74.013124217512; lat:40.7129457424235
```

the log return me the following

```
long:-1.2917738108982455 ; lat:0.71057597166828
```

but what is this ? my map is in GML (apparently) so is that another type of coordinate? how can I get the accurate long/lat? since the building are at the accurate location, there is surely a way

Comment: Those are likely radians, not degrees.  Try `Cesium.Math.toDegrees(n)` and see what you get.

Comment: god I didn't thougt about this, it looks correct but slightly different . anyway Thanks, I believe that is the best i can get !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @emackey said, those are radians. should have seen it.